# How to force update/refresh shipping methods on checkout Magento 2 after adding discounted code (Free shipping))

Tags: magento, magento2

Magetno 2.2.7  (One step checkout module)

```
define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Magento_SalesRule/js/model/payment/discount-messages',
    'mage/storage',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader'
], function (ko, $, quote, urlManager, errorProcessor, messageContainer, storage, $t, getPaymentInformationAction,
    totals, fullScreenLoader
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (couponCode, isApplied) {
        var quoteId = quote.getQuoteId(),
            url = urlManager.getApplyCouponUrl(couponCode, quoteId),
            message = $t('Your coupon was successfully applied!!');

        fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

        return storage.put(
            url,
            {},
            false
        ).done(function (response) {
            var deferred;

            if (response) {
                deferred = $.Deferred();

                isApplied(true);
                totals.isLoading(true);
                getPaymentInformationAction(deferred);
                $.when(deferred).done(function () {
                    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    totals.isLoading(false);
                    console.log("trigger update");
                });
                messageContainer.addSuccessMessage({
                    'message': message
                });
            }
        }).fail(function (response) {
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
            totals.isLoading(false);
            errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, change files set-coupon-code.js, cancel-cupon.js (vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\view\frontend\web\js\action). Maybe this isn't best solution but works.

set-coupon-code.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Customer store credit(balance) application
 */
define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Magento_SalesRule/js/model/payment/discount-messages',
    'mage/storage',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader'
], function (ko, $, quote, urlManager, errorProcessor, messageContainer, storage, $t, getPaymentInformationAction,
    totals, fullScreenLoader
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (couponCode, isApplied) {
        var quoteId = quote.getQuoteId(),
            url = urlManager.getApplyCouponUrl(couponCode, quoteId),
            message = $t('Your coupon was successfully applied!');

        fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

        return storage.put(
            url,
            {},
            false
        ).done(function (response) {
            var deferred;

            if (response) {
                deferred = $.Deferred();

                isApplied(true);
                totals.isLoading(true);
                getPaymentInformationAction(deferred);
                $.when(deferred).done(function () {
                    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    totals.isLoading(false);
                    var select2 = document.getElementById("checkout-review-table").getElementsByClassName("item_qty")[0];
                    select2.addEventListener('change',function(){
                    });
                    select2.value = Number(select2.value) + 1;
                    select2.value = Number(select2.value) - 1;
                    select2.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

                });
                messageContainer.addSuccessMessage({
                    'message': message
                });
            }
        }).fail(function (response) {
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
            totals.isLoading(false);
            errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

cancel-cupon.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Customer store credit(balance) application
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Magento_SalesRule/js/model/payment/discount-messages',
    'mage/storage',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader'
], function ($, quote, urlManager, errorProcessor, messageContainer, storage, getPaymentInformationAction, totals, $t,
  fullScreenLoader
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (isApplied) {
        var quoteId = quote.getQuoteId(),
            url = urlManager.getCancelCouponUrl(quoteId),
            message = $t('Your coupon was successfully removed!');

        messageContainer.clear();
        fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

        return storage.delete(
            url,
            false
        ).done(function () {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();

            totals.isLoading(true);
            getPaymentInformationAction(deferred);
            $.when(deferred).done(function () {
                isApplied(false);
                totals.isLoading(false);
                fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();

                var select2 = document.getElementById("checkout-review-table").getElementsByClassName("item_qty")[0];
                    select2.addEventListener('change',function(){
                    });
                    select2.value = Number(select2.value) + 1;
                    select2.value = Number(select2.value) - 1;
                    select2.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

            });
            messageContainer.addSuccessMessage({
                'message': message
            });
        }).fail(function (response) {
            totals.isLoading(false);
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
            errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```